# Unknown error parsing query

Tags: soql

I am writing Soql Query getting unknown error parsing query

```
[select id, Order.AccountId, Product__c, [select Product2.Last_30_days_sold__c from Product2] 
from OrderItem  
where Product__c  != null and createddate >= LAST_N_DAYS:30 
order by Last_30_days_sold__c desc 
limit 50000000]
```

Answer (score 3):

Subqueries are enclosed in parentheses (`()`), not square braces (`[]`). Parent records are selected directly through a relationship. At no point does SOQL use `[]` characters.

> select id, Order.AccountId,Product2Id,Product2.Last_30_Days_Sold__c FROM OrderItem ...

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the [WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_generate_wsdl.htm) I don't think a subquery is the correct thing to do. The WSDL shows that Product2 is a lookup, not a child relationship.

Instead, your query should be something like this:

```
[
    SELECT id, Order.AccountId, Product__c, Product2.Last_30_days_sold__c
    FROM OrderItem
    WHERE Product__c  != null 
        AND createddate >= LAST_N_DAYS:30 
    ORDER BY Product2.Last_30_days_sold__c DESC
    LIMIT 50000000
]
```

From the WSDL:

```
<complexType name="OrderItem">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ens:sObject">
            <sequence>
                ...
                <element name="Product2" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Product2"/>
                ...
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

If it was a child relationship the type would be **tns:QueryResult** instead.

**Subquery Syntx:**

Even though a subquery is not correct, the syntax of the subquery is also wrong (as sfdcfox stated). SOQL doesn't use [] for suqueries, instead, () is used. Also, in the subquery you don't use dot notation.

**subquery example:**

```
[
    SELECT Id, Name, CustomField__c,
        (SELECT Id FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account
]
```

Subqueries also use the plural name which is what pointed me to the fact that a subquery may not have been correct in your instance (why I checked the wsdl to begin with). If Product2 was a child relationship, the query would have been something like Product2s or Products2 (obviously these a goofy, just trying to illustrate the point).